# Differentiation- proof by Induction

Tags: calculus, induction, chain-rule

Here is my problem:
    "Suppose f is a differentiable function whose domain is $(-\infty,\infty)$. We define an infinite sequence of functions $f_n(x)$ as follows:

$f_1(x)=f(x), f_2(x)=f(f_1(x))$, and so on. 
That is, 
$f_n(x)= f(f_{n-1}(x))$ for $n\geq 2$.

State an explicit formula for $\frac{d}{dx}[f_n(x)]$ in which the only derivative is $f'$ and then prove that your formula is correct using Mathematical Induction"

So far, I have found that 
$\frac{d}{dx} f_2(x)= f'(f(x))\cdot f'(x)$

$\frac{d}{dx} f_3(x)= f'(f(f(x)))\cdot f'(f(x))\cdot f'(x)$

I saw a pattern an my formula is $f'(x)\cdot f'(f(x))\cdot f'(f(f(x)))\cdots f'(f(\dots(f(x))\dots))$ for as large n is.

I am not sure how to prove this using induction though....
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my exercise, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context: What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc. Something to both show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: I recommend visiting [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) in order to learn a bit about how to type mathematics on this site.  I've taken the liberty of typesetting several of your equations above which helps improve the readability of the question.

Comment: It's helpful to also define $f_0(x) = x$ — the last term in your two examples is $f'(f_0(x))$.

Comment: The usual symbol for $f_n$ is $f^{\circ n}$.

Answer (score 0):

Heh. You're un UMTYMP, right? :)

Here's a hint:

Try to find $~\frac{d}{dx}[f_2(x)]~$ first, then $~\frac{d}{dx}[f_3(x)]~$. You should see a pattern that is provable by induction.

Edit: Write the formula using big pi notation. Assume this formula works for n=k. Now, prove that it still holds true when you plug in $~n=k+1~$ using the previous assumption.

Comment: Yes I am form UMTYMP, how did you know? And I edited my question for further clarification.

Comment: And, I know because that's the professional problem for this week. You should ask on Moodle if you want instructors' help. I don't think I am allowed to give you the answer.

Comment: Thanks @JMoravitz that makes it much more readable